# Find document in a hierarchical MongoDB collection by any field

Tags: mongodb-query

Given the sample document below in MongoDB, is there a way to find all the documents that have someone with the name "John"?  That is, the query would return records 1 and 3 below.  I can't use `{"name" : "John" }` or `{"father.name" : "John" }` as both only return a single record.

```
{ "id": 1, "name": "John" },
{ "id": 2, "name": "Sam" },
{ "id": 3, "name": "Fred", "father": { "name": "John" } }
```

Comment: How about combining both with $or ?

Comment: yes, that certainly works, Thee ... however, I was really wondering whether it could find *all* records rather than just two (sorry, I should have been more clear).

Comment: Are the fields you want to check like "father", "mother" limited? Is the depth of nesting limited?

Comment: Are you able to figure it out? I'm interested in your approach. I think it might be better if you store only 1 level of relationship and put the deeper relationship at the top level instead.

Comment: No, I haven't figured it out yet.  Ideally the query would search any depth of nested documents, but the collection I'm trying to search is only 2 levels deep.